# How can I pass common resource intensive objects to subclasses?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

We need to implement a functionality to generate the huge xml document to export the records.

Our situations are like the following:

- Some objects are resource intensive to load and should be loaded only
  once for each iteration
- 3 developers in the team need to divide the works
- There are 12 big sections in the XML document

So, I made the interface to generate Xml

```
public interface IGenerateXml
    {
        ResourceIntensiveObject1 Student { get; set; }
        ResourceIntensiveObject2 Course { get; set; }
        ResourceIntensiveObject3 User { get; set; }

        XmlElement Generate();
    }
```

I don't want to declare the common objects in each class.  So, I made the base class which can be used to pass those objects.  Not all sections need to get access to those objects, but majority of them need them.

```
public class GenerateXmlBase 
    {
        public ResourceIntensiveObject1 Student { get; set; }
        public ResourceIntensiveObject2 Course { get; set; }
        public ResourceIntensiveObject3 User { get; set; }
    }
```

Then create classes, implement the interface and inherit the base class

```
public class GenerateSection1 : GenerateXmlBase, IGenerateXml
{
    public XmlElement Generate()
    {
        // some codes to return Xml
        return null;
    }
}

public class GenerateSection2 : GenerateXmlBase, IGenerateXml
{
    public XmlElement Generate()
    {
        // some codes to return Xml
        return null;
    }
}

public class GenerateSection3 : GenerateXmlBase, IGenerateXml
{
    public XmlElement Generate()
    {
        // some codes to return Xml
        return null;
    }
}
```

In that way, I got the testable, easily mockable classes for each section.
However, when I try to combine all these codes together, I got some duplicate codes which do the same thing again and again (assigning created objects to classes).  Please see the following code:

```
void GenerateAndSaveXmlDocument()
        {
            // loading these classes are resource intensive and takes time
            // so load only once and pass down to the sub classes
            var _student = new ResourceIntensiveObject1();
            var _course = new ResourceIntensiveObject2();
            var _user = new ResourceIntensiveObject3();

            IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection1 = new GenerateSection1();
            IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection2 = new GenerateSection2();
            IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection3 = new GenerateSection3();
            // code goes on for other 9 classes

            // <---------  this is where repetitive codes start
            clsGenerateSection1.Student = _student;
            clsGenerateSection1.Course = _course;
            clsGenerateSection1.User = _user;

            clsGenerateSection2.Student = _student;
            clsGenerateSection2.Course = _course;
            clsGenerateSection2.User = _user;

            // this one needs only 2 classes
            clsGenerateSection3.Student = _student;
            clsGenerateSection3.Course = _course;

            // and other 9 classes codes which use 2/3 objects
            // ........

            // generate, combine and save final xml
        }
```

I would like to know how I could code efficiently to remove those repetitive codes?

P.S:  I don't want to pass those objects in the `Generate()` method because we are not really sure that how many resource intensive objects we need to generate the XML.  Currently, we looked at only 2 sections and it might be growing in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of repetitive code comes from property assignment statements. Consider an abstract base class `GenerateXmlAbstract` which is a combination of `GenerateXmlBase` and `IGenerateXml`:

```
public abstract class GenerateXmlAbstract {
    public ResourceIntensiveObject1 Student { get; private set; }
    public ResourceIntensiveObject2 Course { get; private set; }
    public ResourceIntensiveObject3 User { get; private set; }

    public GenerateXmlAbstract(
            ResourceIntensiveObject1 student,
            ResourceIntensiveObject2 course,
            ResourceIntensiveObject3 user
    ) {
        Student = student;
        Course = course;
        User = user;
    }

    public abstract XmlElement Generate();
}
```

The key thing to notice is that property assignment statements are in the abstract base class constructor. This way, the constructor can be called in inheriting classes:

```
public class GenerateSection1 : GenerateXmlAbstract {
    public GenerateSection1(
            ResourceIntensiveObject1 student,
            ResourceIntensiveObject2 course,
            ResourceIntensiveObject3 user
    ) : base(student, course, user) { }

    public XmlElement Generate() {
        // some codes to return Xml
        return null;
    }
}
```

Inheriting concrete classes can then be instantiated by passing the necessary dependencies to the constructor, which also avoids passing them in the `Generate` method:

```
void GenerateAndSaveXmlDocument() {
    // loading these classes are resource intensive and takes time
    // so load only once and pass down to the sub classes
    var _student = new ResourceIntensiveObject1();
    var _course = new ResourceIntensiveObject2();
    var _user = new ResourceIntensiveObject3();

    IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection1 = new GenerateSection1(_student, _course, _user);
    IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection2 = new GenerateSection2(_student, _course, _user);
    IGenerateXml clsGenerateSection3 = new GenerateSection3(_student, _course, _user);
    // code goes on for other 9 classes

    // generate, combine and save final xml
}
```

For classes that don't use all three dependencies you might consider passing null, defining another constructor in `GenerateXmlAbstract` class which takes one or two parameters or building a more fine grained inheritance tree where not all classes contain all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign the properties in the loop?

```
var sections = new List <IGenerateXml>() 
{
    new GenerateSection1(),
    new GenerateSection2(),
    new GenerateSection3()
}

foreach(var section in sections)
{
    section.Student = _student;
    section.Course = _course;
    section.User = _user;
}
```